# Java - error, empty String in treeSet

Tags: java, string, treeset

I have been going over this thing all day, line by line and I cannot figure out why I'm getting an empty String error. The program reads a text file and the output from the first part is correct, however, the second part gives me the empty String error.
Output is supposed to look like this -

COMMERICAL

FARM

LAND

RESIDENTIAL

101   600000.00

105   30000.00

106   200000.00

107   1040000.00

110   250000.00

Mine looks like this -

COMMERCIAL

FARM

LAND

RESIDENTIAL

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1011)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at my.report.agentReport.agentValue(agentReport.java:84)
    at my.report.agentReport.main(agentReport.java:41)
```

That block of errors repeats itself 7 times which happens to be the number of lines in the text file.
This is what the text file looks like -

110001    commercial    500000.00 101

110223    residential      100000.00 101

110020    commercial   1000000.00 107

110333    land                30000.00   105

110442    farm               200000.00  106

110421    land                40000.00   107

112352    residential       250000.00  110

I have tried more things than I can count in the past 2 days to no avail.
I'm running out of options. I'd really appreciate any help that anyone could give me.

Finally, here's the code...

```
        package my.report;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class agentReport {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    // get input from user (file name)
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Name of file to process: ");
    String inputFile = console.next();
    BufferedWriter pwfo = null;
    try {
        pwfo = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\agentReport.txt", true));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrintWriter pwo = new PrintWriter(pwfo);

    //Construct treeSet (property type)
    Set<String> propertyType = pType(inputFile);

    // Print property types 
    for (String type : propertyType) {
        System.out.println(type);
        pwo.println(type);
    }

    //Construct treeSet (agent IDs and values) 
    Set<String> agentReport = agentValue(inputFile);

    // Print agent IDs and values 
    for (String tail : agentReport) {
        {
            System.out.println(tail);
            pwo.println(tail);
        }
    }
    pwo.flush();
    pwo.close();
}

// read input and alphabetized property types in uppercase
public static Set<String> pType(String inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException //Construct treeSet to return property types
{
    Set<String> type = new TreeSet<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));

    // use while loop and delimiter to select specific characters for set
    in.useDelimiter("[1234567890. ]");

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        type.add(in.next().toUpperCase());
    }
    in.close();
    return type;
}

//  read file and print out agent ID's and property values
public static Set<String> agentValue(String inputFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    TreeSet<String> tail = new TreeSet<>();
    SortedMap<String, Number> agentValue = new TreeMap<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFile));
    String line;

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        try {
            line = in.nextLine();
            String[] fields = line.split("[\\s+]");
            String agentId = (fields[3]);
            Double pValue = Double.parseDouble(fields[2]);

            if (agentValue.containsKey(agentId)) {
                pValue += agentValue.get(agentId).doubleValue();
            }
            agentValue.put(agentId, pValue);

            // Create keyMap with keys and values

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Set<String> keySet = agentValue.keySet();
        for (String key : keySet) {
            Number value = agentValue.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
            tail.add(key + ":" + value);
        }
    }
    return tail;
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I'm new to Java so I'm not the best at using it and with what I do know, it hasn't helped me with this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `pType` method, you have used certain delimiters for scanner: -

```
in.useDelimiter("[1234567890. ]");
```

Now, when you read this line: -

```
110001 commercial 500000.00 101
```

You will get an empty string between the each numeric value. Which will give you some problems, if you don't pre-check it.

See this sample code for e.g: -

```
String str = "110001 commercial 500000.00 101";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str);
scanner.useDelimiter("[0-9. ]");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print("*" + scanner.next() + "*-");
}
```

**Output: -**

```
**-**-**-**-**-**-*commercial*-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-
```

As you can see those pairs of `**`, which denotes the empty string read between each numeric values.

You can add a test for empty string inside the `while` loop, to avoid adding it: -

```
String line = "";
while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (!(line = in.next()).isEmpty()) {
        type.add(line.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. I totally missed that. I guess I was thinking that wouldn't effect the second part of the code. Removing the delimiter changes my output drastically. It's not correct but there's a lot more to it. When I add that if statement under the while, the scanner part is giving me an error - cannot find symbol variable scanner - not sure how to remedy that.

Comment: @neveser. Sorry, `scanner` is the Scanner reference, I generally use. You have used `in`, so replace `scanner.next()` with `in.next()`

Comment: Ahh... I see. Now my output consists of the 5 agent IDs followed by the property types, then the 7 blocks of errors. So there's still empty strings there. Somehow the property values aren't getting where they need to be.

Comment: I've playing with this today and haven't made any more progress. There's definetely something wrong in that second half of code that I'm not seeing. Can't get the empty String error remedied.

Comment: OK, some has pointed out some of my many other problems with this. I think I've got it now.